# laravel add class action does not working

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am working with laravel 8 and I am trying to upload multiple images. When I click remove and after add actions then add action does not working.

```
<div class="input-group realprocode control-group lst increment">
  <input type="file" name="filenames[]" class="myfrm form-control">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"> <i class="fldemo glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clone hide">
  <div class="realprocode control-group lst input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
    <input type="file" name="filenames[]" class="myfrm form-control">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fldemo glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-success").click(function() {
    var lsthmtl = $(".clone").html();
    $(".increment").after(lsthmtl);
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".btn-danger", function() {
    $(this).parents(".realprocode").remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: I have checked and it's working fine when I click remove and after add actions but I have faced other issue like while the second time performs add action then input clone multiple times so is this your issue?( second time perform two input added, third time perform three input added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script>
                    
         $(document).ready(function() {
            
            $(".btn-success").click(function(){

                let cloneId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99) + 1);

                var cloneHtml = `<div class="clone hide" id="clone_` + cloneId + `">
                    <div class="realprocode control-group lst input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
                        <input type="file" name="filenames[]" class="myfrm form-control">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" id="remove_` + cloneId +`" type="button"><i class="fldemo glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`;

                $(".increment").after(cloneHtml);
            });  

            $("body").on("click", ".btn-danger", function(e){
                $(this).closest('.clone').remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to close the clone div into the HTML so please close clone div into the HTML and your issue will resolve please find the below code:

```
<div class="input-group realprocode control-group lst increment">
  <input type="file" name="filenames[]" class="myfrm form-control">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"> <i class="fldemo glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clone hide">
  <div class="realprocode control-group lst input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
    <input type="file" name="filenames[]" class="myfrm form-control">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fldemo glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```